# Google Adsense for smartphones

Tags: adsense, smartphone, public-html

I have a website which uses `Adsense` for the homepage etcetera. Now, I want to replace this one with an mobile ad, also from Adsense. My question is: is this possible? I tried setting the desktop ads to `display: none;` and implementing a `chtml` encoded ad, but I get nothing at all...

I have no subdomain for my mobile website; it's just a responsive site. Doesn't that count?

PS: I am testing it on an `iPhone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

Yes it is possible. **Patience** is the key word. I set them both and used `display: none` for the desktop version if it is a mobile browser. Now it works like a charm :)